# JSON Parsing with awk

Tags: macos, awk, grep

i have huge chunk of server logs. The structure as below.  I am trying to extract number unique requestIds values from the json file.  requestId is a key and there could be many number of same requestId values.  I want to extract unique requestIds.  The order if the fields can be different in the the inputfile.

**input.txt**

```
{
   "timestamp":"2021-05-06T20:33:47.986Z",
   "logger_name":"c.a.p.r.engine.Taxengine",
   "thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-18",
   "level":"INFO",
   "serviceArchPath":"rb.amxp.Taxfiler",
   "process":"NA",
   "message":"Deployment successfully",
   "requestId":"CFLGftt2hfrBhr6Ltyjdx"
},
{
   "newField":"tempfield", 
   "timestamp":"2021-05-06T20:33:47.986Z",
   "logger_name":"c.a.p.r.engine.Taxengine",
   "thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-18",
   "level":"INFO",
   "serviceArchPath":"rb.amxp.Taxfiler",
   "process":"NA",
   "message":"Deployment successfully",
   "requestId":"DELGongDKGbehr6Lsak"
},
{
   "timestamp":"2021-05-06T20:33:47.986Z",
   "logger_name":"c.a.p.r.engine.Taxengine",
   "thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-18",
   "level":"INFO",
   "serviceArchPath":"rb.amxp.Taxfiler",
   "process":"NA",
   "message":"Deployment successfully",
   "requestId":"CFLGftt2hfrBhr6Ltyjdx"
},
```

Can i get help to Log number of requestIds and display them.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: display-em `grep 'requestId'  ...`   count-em  `grep -c 'requestId'  ...`  pipe through `sort -u` for distinct count  `uniq -c` for how many of each .... in general don't use awk here. Simpler tools for these simpler things and `jq` if it _needs_ awk

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\"" } /requestId/ { print $(NF - 1) }' input.txt
```

This basically uses `"` as the field separator and extract the penultimate field if it sees `requestId`.

Ouptut:

```
CFLGftt2hfrBhr6Ltyjdx
DELGongDKGbehr6Lsak
CFLGftt2hfrBhr6Ltyjdx
```

You can then pipe it to `sort --unique` if needed.

But I am not quite sure whether awk is the tool for this task. As the comment suggests, other simpler tools or json-targeted tools might be better.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, if `jq` is available, please try:

```
jq -r '[.[].requestId] | unique | .[]' input.txt
```

Output:

```
CFLGftt2hfrBhr6Ltyjdx
DELGongDKGbehr6Lsak
```

Please note the input file is reformatted by removing the trailing comma
and surrounding by square brackets to make a valid json file.